# Debug Helm in k8s-bake action

Tags: kubernetes-helm, github-actions

Azure/k8s-bake action is failing with the following message

```
Running helm dependency update command..
Error: Error: Failed to run bake action. Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/helm' failed with exit code 1
    at ExecState._setResult (/__w/_actions/azure/k8s-bake/v1/node_modules/@actions/exec/lib/toolrunner.js:547:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (/__w/_actions/azure/k8s-bake/v1/node_modules/@actions/exec/lib/toolrunner.js:530:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/__w/_actions/azure/k8s-bake/v1/node_modules/@actions/exec/lib/toolrunner.js:430:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
```

**Step Detail**

```
    - name: Bake helm values
      id: bake
      uses: azure/k8s-bake@v1
      with:
        renderEngine: 'helm'
        helmChart: ${{ env.HELM_CHART }} 
        overrides: |
          nameOverride: ${{ env.KUBE_NAMESPACE }}
          image.repository: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE }}
          image.tag: ${{ github.sha }}
          ingress.hosts[0].host: ${{ secrets.API_DOMAIN }}
          ingress.hosts[0].paths: ${{ env.INGRESS_PATH }}
```

Base container is set to `alpine/helm:3.6.3`

How can I enable debug for the helm to know the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Set the silent flag to `'false'`.

```
    - name: Bake helm values
      id: bake
      uses: azure/k8s-bake@v1
      with:
        renderEngine: 'helm'
        silent: 'false' # set this to get more verbose helm command logs
        helmChart: ${{ env.HELM_CHART }} 
        overrides: |
          nameOverride: ${{ env.KUBE_NAMESPACE }}
          image.repository: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_IMAGE }}
          image.tag: ${{ github.sha }}
          ingress.hosts[0].host: ${{ secrets.API_DOMAIN }}
          ingress.hosts[0].paths: ${{ env.INGRESS_PATH }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).